# Is there is a way to check a word is same to another word?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**I am making bot that check if there is a user who said bad words. For some reason, it didn't do anything**

```
    var badWord = "not"
    let splittedMessage = message.content.split(" ")
    
    for (let i=0; i < splittedMessage.length; i++) {
      for (let u=0; u < badWords.length; u++) {
        if (splittedMessage[i] === badWords[u]) {
          badWord = "yes"
        }
      }
    }
    
    if (badWord === "yes") {
      console.log("Deleting message")
      message.delete()
      message.channel.send(`${message.author} has been warned. Reason: Bad word usage`)
      message.author.send(`You has been warned in DoGame. Reason: Bad word usage`)
    }
```

**Bad words array**

```
const badWords = ["fuck","hell","shit","bitch","asshole","bastard"]
```

Comment: Instead, just try looping through only the bad word list and `if(message.content.indexOf(badWords[u]) >= 0)` then the message contains a bad word.

Comment: The above comment is correct. You should also make the `message` all lower-case, to make it match.

Comment: None of the solutions given so far consider normalizing case before comparing. "Hell" and "hell" are not the same when using indexOf() or includes(). With that said this is not as simple as it seems. For example "shell" and "hello" include "hell"

Comment: Just as an addendum, in general, try your best to avoid nested loops running all the way. This is a bad practice.

Comment: Yes you must normalize, otherwise special combined characters will also return false even if they match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this where you loop over the message and then use `includes` to see if the word exists in the array.

```
const splitMessage = message.content.split(" ");
for (const word of splitMessage) {
    if (badWords.includes(word)) {
        // bad word detected. handle in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[An Idiot's Guide](https://anidiots.guide/examples/miscellaneous-examples#swear-detector) Has a great example of how to detect swear words in the message without the need of loops.

```
const swearWords = ["darn", "shucks", "frak", "shite"];
if (swearWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))) {
  message.reply("Oh no you said a bad word!!!");
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is "hell" would match "hello"

Comment: Big advantage to using `some` is that it will stop searching after the first match!

Comment: Then, instead, just use find

Comment: `.find()` is intended to return an actual result element, best to use `.some()` since you want a boolean